# Localizing iOS "More" button

Tags: ios, user-interface, internationalization, tabbar

I am having UITabBar in my application.

The thing is that I am developing in language not being currently supported by Apple. The need is to localize some system elements which currently appear in English. One of them is button "More" on UITabBar.

Could anybody give me a hand how to do it? I have read that it is not possible to change that button title in simple way.

Big thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to do.

1. Localize the storyboard (eg: text on Buttons)
2. Create a Localizable.strings for other custom strings not inside the storyboard
3. Localize any UI Elements (eg: images) that contain text

You may follow the exact steps from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

For only button:
[image]

If without Storyboard:-

I think your code will be like

```
[self.myButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"More", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

inside Localizable.strings for that language

```
 "More"="THE TRANSLATION";
```

**Update:**

Make a custom class for `UITabBarController` and add the following code in `viewDidLoad`

```
UITabBarItem * tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yo", nil) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"] tag:0];
[[self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTabBarItem:tabBarItem];
[[self.moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Yo", nil)];
```

Then you can just use `Localizable.strings` to localize the text. I purposely put "Yo" on the test project.

[image]

Comment: I need only the way for More button which is not so obvious.

Comment: If your button is inside the storyboard, then you just need to localize the storyboard. You may check the section "Adding a Spanish Localization" from the link I gave above. You will see a new file created under the storyboard. I attached screen shot from one of my projects.

Comment: I am writing about system button More.  Additionally I dont use storyboards in that project.

Comment: If it is not inside storyboard, then you have to use Localizable.strings  file. Just updated my answer above.

Comment: That is not about that. It is not about that kind of localization. The problem is there how to change the More button on UiTabBar which is not set by user but comes from iOS. But thanks for trying...

Comment: I think I understand your question now. Just updated the answer.